# VTK: Disable Anchor Picking/Dragging in vtkCaptionWidget

Tags: c++, vtk

I am trying to prevent the anchor in the vtkCaptionWidget from being interacted with by the user (http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Widgets/CaptionWidget). It seems straight forward to just call something like:

```
captionRepresentation->GetAnchorRepresentation()->SetPickable(0);
```

or

```
captionRepresentation->GetAnchorRepresentation()->SetDragable(0);
```

however these do not appear to do anything. I have tried a number of different combinations of disable calls on the widget, representation and anchor representation. I think I am missing something.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out what I actually wanted to do was disable the handle/leader component of the widget. To do this I had to create a new class that inherited from vtkCaptionWidget and then added the following function to disable the internal vtkHandleWidget:

```
void SetHandleEnabled(int enabling)
{
    this->HandleWidget->SetEnabled(enabling);
}
```

Comment: When I did this still leader is dragable !?!

Answer (score 1):

Turn off the interaction of a widget by

```
myWidget->ProcessEventsOff();
```

Comment: Unfortunately this only disables the interaction on the caption portion of the widget. The handle is still movable.